# unable to locate APT file on Mac when installing libxml2

Tags: java, r, xml, azure

I'm trying to install libxml2 on my Mac as R studio on Microsoft Azure is unable to install certain libraries like Tidyverse and Quanteda without XML library. So, when I ran the command below on Terminal, I got the following prompt. I did some googling and found that Mac doesn't have an APT file in java. I found couple of answers of similar questions asked earlier on SO, but they didn't really answer this question. How should I fix this? Thanks.

```
sudo apt install libxml2_dev  


Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

Comment: `apt` is part of the debian "universe". You need to use the package manager of the OS that you're working with. Are you sure you're working on ubuntu/debian?

Comment: As per this document:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/hosting-rserver-and-rstudio-on-azure/ba-p/744389, the Rstudio on Azure works on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: FWIW, when I install packages in Ubuntu (via Docker containers), I use `libxml2-dev`.